# Does using -o with ssh not read the config file?

Tags: ssh

The title pretty much explains my entire question. The reason I'm asking is that I have a specific IdentityFile set for a certain host but the command that is being run which is out of my control uses a `ssh -o` to set a ConnectionTimeout. Does this tell the ssh client to not read the config file?

Comment: Check out the options for SSH by typing `man ssh`

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't:

```
[madhatter@anni ~]$ whoami
madhatter
[madhatter@anni ~]$ ssh rembrandt whoami
tyates
[madhatter@anni ~]$ ssh rembrandt -o TCPKeepAlive=yes whoami
tyates
```

As you can see, the config file is being read to set my username on the remote server (which is why it changes).  This behaviour is unaffected by the user of `-o TCPKeepAlive=yes`.